# How to find out the location of unrecognized selector exception in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do I go about finding out where in my code caused the following exception?

```
2012-08-15 09:24:27.414 TestProject[82870:17303] -[TestObj doIt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1106f320
```

Comment: unfortunately I believe there is now way to do that in an easy way, you will need to debug it and search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it: Add a breakpoint to capture all exceptions, that will give you the line of code where you are getting the exception. From the console, you will get the same message you are posting on your question, so, use the pointer address to print the object that is getting the exception. If the object is garbage(the debugger wont print it), that means you are overreleasing an object. If you have zombies enabled, you will find a prefix NSZombie__ on your class name. That also means overrelease. If you get a different class than the one you are expecting, you are switching the objects at some point and sending a message to the wrong object.

Comment: This didn't solve my issue but I appreciate the detailed explanation and this can come in handy for similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to the breakpoints navigator (on the left)
- at the bottom you have a +,
- add an exception breakpoint on all exceptions

Answer (score 1):

set a breakpoint for thrown exceptions. by default, it will pause when an exception is thrown -- there you will see the backtrace and values.

if it's completely random (e.g. not reproducible), then you may have best luck running Instruments with zombies enabled.

Comment: Yes I did that but when the exception hit Xcode is breaking in the wrong spot (main.m).

Comment: then continue if that's not the breakpoint you are interested in